# MongoDB - Logging write & read queries

Tags: mongodb, logging, mongodb-query

We're trying to log read & write operations in MongoDB. We want the actual queries to be logged to the file.
We're using the following configuration (in the primary node in the replica set):

```
logpath=/.../mongodb.log
logappend=true
profile=2
slowms=1
diaglog=3
verbose=true
vvvv=true
```

To my understanding, this should work. However, in the log we can only see what was the type of query (drop/insert/update etc.) and the collection, not the actual query that was executed.

EDIT: To clarify: We want to log the read/write queries to the **regular mongodb log file** (same as you can do in MySQL for example).

What could be the problem? Anyone has any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What version of mongodb?

Answer (score 3):

First of all please note:

> Because the database profiler can negatively impact performance, only
>   enable profiling for strategic intervals and as minimally as possible
>   on production systems.

You can also enable profiler per database to reduce the profiling impact on the mongo instance. `slowms=1` is redundant in your case `profile=2` will log all queries no matter how long they take.

Here's a simple test to check that no additional configration required to view profile data:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
db.testProf.insert({x : 1})
db.testProf.update({x : 1}, {$set : {x : 2}})
db.testProf.find({x : 2})
db.testProf.remove({x : 2})
db.setProfilingLevel(0)
```

Now you can query profile data for detailed info:

```
db.system.profile.find().pretty()
```

This should display the runtime info for each operation run above. Here's an extract from update operation details:

```
"op" : "update",
    "ns" : "profDb.testProf",
    "query" : {
            "x" : 1
    },
    "updateobj" : {
            "$set" : {
                    "x" : 2
            }
    },
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nupdated" : 1,
    "fastmod" : true,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "lockStats" : {
            "timeLockedMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(0),
                    "w" : NumberLong(1131)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(0),
                    "w" : NumberLong(5)
            }
    }
```

The `query` field contains the update criteria while the `updateobj` field contains the update operation run against the document.
If you do the same stuff and the `query` field is still empty probably you run update, remove, etc for all documents.

For more info on how to interpret profile data please refer to the docs - [Database Profiler Output](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-profiler/)

**EDIT:**
Just noticed `diaglog=3` configuration. This one is mostly used for recording and replaying operation. This keeps a very verbose logs and also negatively impacts performance, I think you should skip it. Profiling is enough to achive want you want.

**EDIT:**
Not sure why you need profile data saved into a file as I think it's much more convinient to have it in a collection. You can query it as any other collection for the data you are interested in. I'm not aware of any way to stream profile data directly to a file but you can export it any time like that:

```
mongoexport --db profDb --collection system.profile --out profiler.json
```

You are right, diaglog writes all data to a file, but this one is of internal format, which is not user friendly and hard to read.

> diaglog is for internal use and not intended for most users.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I misunderstood it, but you suggested to view the queries in the mongo shell, but we need them to be logged to the log file...

Comment: not sure why you need it in a file anyway see my update

Comment: It seems very strange to me that you can't simply log the queries to the regular mongodb log file (same as MySQL for example). The solution you suggested isn't very practical for our purpose.

Comment: Yeah, you can easily do it with MSSQL as well, I will be glad if someone chime in with a better solution as your question is a very interesting one, but just out of curiosity, no intention to argue, why do you need it in the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn database profiling, which writes all operations to a collection:

`db.setProfilingLevel(2)`

There is a minor impact on performance.

Docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

**EDIT:**
To view the profiler data, you can read the `db.system.profile` collection.

Comment: Isn't it the same thing as `profile=2` in the configuration file?

Comment: That's correct. In order to view the profiler data, you can read the db.system.profile collection; that is where the data is being written to, not the log. (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#view-profiler-data)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how is it different from what I did (and didn't work).